# How do I save many options with Django ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Ho ho ho!

What would be the best solution to the following problem?

I have a section model, which contains many question models, which contains a few choice models:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    section_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    section_description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.section_text

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.section_text)
        super(Section, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Question(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The ModelForm is kept simple since I just want to edit the number of votes:

```
class ChoiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['votes']
```

Not sure if I should pass pk, question_id or slug in url:

```
url(
    #regex=r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/$',
    #regex=r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    regex=r'^vote/$',
    view=vote,
    name='vote'
),
```

Within HTML I display all questions + choices that belong to a section (via question_list):

```
{% if question_list %}      
    <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' %}" method="post">    
    {% for question in question_list %}
        <fieldset>
            <legend>{{ question.question_text }}</legend>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
                <input type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
                <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
            {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
        <input class="button small" type="submit" value="Weiter" />
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Finally, the view. Here I'm not sure what the christmas tree I'm doing:

```
class SectionOverview(ListView):
    model = Section
    context_object_name = 'section_list'
    template_name = 'itbarometer/umfrage.html'

def vote(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChoiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('polls:thanks')
    else:
        form = ChoiceForm()

    return render(request, 'polls:detail', {'form': form,})
```

What I basically want to accomplish, is to save all user input (user has to check all radio buttons -- maybe later multiple choice & textfields) to the database.

All it does now is redirecting me to an empty page /vote/

What am I missing?

Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not using your views, templates, or forms properly. Try to keep things simple. Let's start off with the form.

**Your Form**

You should edit the individual fields to reflect how you want them presented in the template.  For example, if you wanted the users to choose from a drop-down list of questions, you would do the following in your ModelForm.  Please note that it is possible to pull this from the DB itself, but this for illustrative purposes.

```
QUESTION_CHOICES=(
('text saved in DB', 'Question 1'),
('text saved in DB', 'Question 2'),
)

class MyModel(ModelForm):
questions = forms.ChoiceField(choices=QUESTION_CHOICES)

class Meta:
    model = MyModel
```

**Useful Links**
[Createing ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example)
[Specifying Widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/)
[Working with Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

**Your Template**

Once you complete your modelform, you will only need to send its instance to the template.  In other words, your template will look similar to this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
      <input id="save_question" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Your View**

It seems like you're trying to mix function-based views with class-based views.  Assuming you intended to use class-based views, there's no need to create a get_vote function.  Instead, override the get() and post() functions.  When the class is called, it will automatically determine whether it is a GET or POST request.  Here's an example of yours.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form=self.get_form(self.get_form_class())
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

**Useful Links**
[Classy CBV](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.list/ListView/)
[Using/Creating Views](http://effectivedjango.com/tutorial/views.html)
[ListView Example](http://effectivedjango.com/tutorial/additional-views.html?highlight=listview)